# Cant count the array in static

Tags: php

My code:

```
const staticList =
        array(
            array('url'=>'http://static0.website.local/', 'token'=>'abc'),
        );
(line:37) const staticNow = staticList[count(staticList)-1];
```

And i got the error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '(' in C:\Dropbox\DevCloud\htdocs\website\root\index.php on line 37
```

**Update:**
Im using PHP 5.6 and error line is 37

Anyway to fix this? Thank you !

Comment: Are you with PHP < 5.6?

Comment: Yes. PHP 5.6 and the error line is: const staticNow = staticList[count(staticList)-1];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Constants can be assigned with scalar values/scalar expressions, but not with dynamic variables or function calls. 
Consider the following allowed usage:

```
const staticList =
        array(
            array('url'=>'http://static0.website.local/', 'token'=>'abc'),
        );

const STATICNOW = staticList[0]["token"];

echo STATICNOW;   // "abc"
```

Comment: Yes, its really cant dynamic. Im change it to another way and ok now. Thanks !